# How is it possible to use p2p connections like in BitTorrent protocol when I do not have public IP?

Tags: networking, bittorrent

How can torrent peers connect to my `bittorrent` client when I do not have public `IP`?

My `tracert` to **google.com**:

```
  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  CISCOF5586 [192.168.1.1]
  2     1 ms     1 ms     2 ms  10.10.10.10
  3     6 ms     1 ms     1 ms  192.168.60.1
  4     2 ms    21 ms     4 ms  core.e-max.sk [188.120.10.1]
  5    11 ms    10 ms    10 ms  six1.e-max.sk [188.120.11.106]
  6    17 ms    16 ms    15 ms  google.peering.cz [91.213.211.170]
  7    16 ms    16 ms    16 ms  108.170.245.33
  8    16 ms    16 ms    16 ms  108.170.238.159
  9    15 ms    15 ms    15 ms  prg03s05-in-f14.1e100.net [172.217.23.206]
```

My `tracert` to one of torrent peer **124.61.4.84**:

```
  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  CISCOF5586 [192.168.1.1]
  2     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  10.10.10.10
  3     2 ms     1 ms     1 ms  192.168.60.1
  4     3 ms     2 ms     6 ms  core.e-max.sk [188.120.10.1]
  5    13 ms    11 ms    14 ms  six1.e-max.sk [188.120.11.106]
  6    10 ms    11 ms    10 ms  st-static-srk141.87-197-252.telecom.sk [87.197.252.141]
  7    14 ms    14 ms    14 ms  80.150.170.81
  8    18 ms    20 ms    19 ms  80.157.131.166
  9   180 ms   180 ms   180 ms  if-ae-3-2.tcore2.fnm-frankfurt.as6453.net [195.219.87.30]
 10   182 ms     *      182 ms  if-ae-12-80.tcore1.fnm-frankfurt.as6453.net [195.219.156.135]
 11   174 ms   175 ms   177 ms  if-ae-6-2.tcore1.av2-amsterdam.as6453.net [195.219.194.149]
 12   182 ms   183 ms   182 ms  if-ae-2-2.tcore2.av2-amsterdam.as6453.net [195.219.194.6]
 13   175 ms   175 ms   173 ms  if-ae-14-2.tcore2.l78-london.as6453.net [80.231.131.160]
 14   175 ms   174 ms   174 ms  if-ae-15-2.tcore2.ldn-london.as6453.net [80.231.131.118]
 15   174 ms   176 ms   173 ms  if-ae-32-2.tcore2.nto-new-york.as6453.net [63.243.216.22]
 16   188 ms   173 ms   173 ms  if-ae-26-2.tcore1.ct8-chicago.as6453.net [216.6.81.29]
 17   176 ms   176 ms   174 ms  if-ae-29-2.tcore2.sqn-san-jose.as6453.net [64.86.21.104]
 18   191 ms   192 ms   189 ms  if-ae-5-2.tcore2.pdi-palo-alto.as6453.net [64.86.21.2]
 19   174 ms   174 ms   174 ms  if-ae-2-2.tcore1.pdi-palo-alto.as6453.net [66.198.127.1]
 20   170 ms   170 ms   178 ms  66.198.127.130
 21   175 ms   170 ms   170 ms  1.208.104.205
 22   368 ms   297 ms   321 ms  203.255.234.105
 23   308 ms   296 ms   314 ms  1.208.167.10
 24   312 ms   316 ms   301 ms  1.213.150.250
 25   299 ms   305 ms   302 ms  1.213.150.166
 26   317 ms   317 ms   300 ms  203.248.129.150
 27   309 ms   308 ms   308 ms  1.213.24.30
 28     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 29   306 ms   311 ms   311 ms  124.61.4.84
```

Comment: What makes you think you don't have a public IP address? Google "what's my ip address?"  That's your public IP.

Comment: I think you know what I mean

Comment: Not unless you state it clearly in your question, no. I failed mind reading in college.

Comment: If your isp has you behind their firewall you have a private ip which will not do port forwarding which bittorrent depends on to work, so if you cannot get your isp to put your ip outside their firewall (public) there is nothing you can do.

Answer (score 0):

They can because they connect to a central bittorrent server which does have a public IP.

Connecting in this way means that the NAT (network address translation) between the clients and server is configured to a particular state. The server can then coordinate two clients, and using this particular state, the clients can connect directly to each other.

The same principle is used more abstractedly in a [STUN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN) server.

No, there is no way for clients behind modern NAT to connect to each other without using some sort of central server. This server is only used to establish the direct connection, so the load on this central server is small.